# find object with position top > x using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

what is the best way to find first element in the html document with the class myClass with position top greater than specified

Comment: Are you looking for the first element with top > specified, or the highest element with top > specified?

Comment: first element, the most important is performance because im searching through all words wrapped with spans

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Wrong** (first answer) :

```
var $elm = jQuery.each($('.myClass'), function() {
    if ($(this).attr('top') > x) return $(this); 
});
```

**Ok** :

```
var $elm;
jQuery.each($('.myClass'), function() {
    if ($(this).attr('top') > x) {
        $elm = $(this);
        return false;
    }
});
```

This solution does not parse all `.myClass` elements, just returns the first one and stops.

Comment: From the [docs](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/): "We can break the $.each() loop at a particular iteration by making the callback function return false. Returning non-false is the same as a continue statement in a for loop; it will skip immediately to the next iteration."

Comment: This solution actually doesn't return any (useful) output at all. Using `jQuery.each`, the return value is always the same as the first argument, the collection. Remember that `return` applies to your inner function, which simply acts as a continue/break like @anthony mentioned. Try using [`.each()`](http://api.jquery.com/each) instead, with an external variable.

Comment: My mistake, i was focused on trying to limit iterations and got it completely wrong in the end :)

Answer (score 4):

Filter the `.myClass` elements based on `position` top, and then get the first element in the collection:

```
var elem = $('.myClass').filter(function() {
    return $(this).position().top > 200;
}).first();
```

This will get you the first element with a distance from the top inside it's containing element above 200px etc. To get the position relative to the document you could use [offset()](http://api.jquery.com/offset/) instead.

If performance is an issue, I guess this is the fastest:

```
var elems = document.getElementsByClassName('myClass'), elem;
for (var i=0;i<elems.length;i++) {
    if (parseInt(elems[i].style.top, 10)>200) {
        elem=elems[i];
        break;
    }
}
```